# convert data.frame in R to another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a very large data.frame in R and I want to convert it to a new dataframe.
Here is a simple case of my df:

```
x <- data.frame(
  location = c("a", "b", "c"),
  samplesize = c(26, 3, 96),
  a1 = c(12, 2, 77),
  a2 = c(24, 1, 31),
  a3 = c(15, 2, 56)
)
```

and here is the df I want:

```
df <- data.frame(
  location = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"),
  sample.size = c(26, 26, 26, 3, 3, 3, 96, 96, 96),
  allele = c(12, 24, 15, 2, 1, 2, 77, 31, 56),
  name = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a1", "a2", "a3")
)
```

Do you have any general function or code which can help me with that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(
    setDT(x),
    id.vars = 1:2,
    value.name = "allele",
    variable.name = "name"
)
```

which gives

```
   location samplesize name allele
1:        a         26   a1     12
2:        b          3   a1      2
3:        c         96   a1     77
4:        a         26   a2     24
5:        b          3   a2      1
6:        c         96   a2     31
7:        a         26   a3     15
8:        b          3   a3      2
9:        c         96   a3     56
```

Answer (score 0):

alternatively

```r
library(tidyverse)

x %>% pivot_longer(-c(location,samplesize), names_to = 'allele', values_to = 'value')


# A tibble: 9 × 4
  location samplesize allele value
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 a                26 a1        12
2 a                26 a2        24
3 a                26 a3        15
4 b                 3 a1         2
5 b                 3 a2         1
6 b                 3 a3         2
7 c                96 a1        77
8 c                96 a2        31
9 c                96 a3        56
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyr)

x %>% pivot_longer(3:5, values_to = "allele", names_to = "name")
```